# API secured by different instances of authentication provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization

I want to create .NET 6 API which (depending on the client) is going to be secured by different AADB2C. For example I have 2 clients every of them has its token created by its own different AADB2C. I have access to all of these AADB2Cs. I have only one API. Let's say that in every http request I have some clientID. Moreover I keep in database relation between clientID and AADB2C authorization options to properly validate token. We stick to the AADB2C only and will not use other authentication providers like Google/Facebook etc.,

How to achieve that?

Maybe you have some other ideas how to have one API secured by multiple authorization provider?

Comment: Do you mean you want to develop an Azure AD B2C multi-tenant application, if that is the case, refer to these articles: [Developing an Azure AD B2C multi-tenant application](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/developing-an-azure-ad-b2c-multi-tenant-application/) and the sample code: [Identity for multi-tenant SaaS apps for small organizations](https://github.com/mrochon/b2csamples/tree/master/Policies/MultiTenant).

Comment: yes exactly, I will take a look. The most important part is to secure api for request with token created by different auth providers.